# NuGet update fails, does not seem to pick up VisualStudioVersion properly?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Windows 2012 R2 build server, TeamCity 8.1.2, nuget.exe 2.8.1

After enabling and testing a build configuration that involved a regular full build clean followed by a NuGet restore, we enabled incremental VCS updates and have enabled NuGet update on our build configuration. The build configuration now fails with this error during NuGet update:

```
[Step 1/4] update: Updating NuGet packages for OurSolutionName.sln
[22:20:10]NuGet command: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg\tools\NuGet.exe update D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\52034b1c4c1ab5f5\OurSolutionName.sln -Verbose -RepositoryPath D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\52034b1c4c1ab5f5\packages
[22:20:10]Starting: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script9174264003705363137.cmd
[22:20:10]in directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\52034b1c4c1ab5f5
[22:20:10]Scanning for projects...
[22:20:10]The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\52034b1c4c1ab5f5\proofs\MvcRouting\MvcRouting\MvcRouting.csproj
[22:20:11]Process exited with code 1
[22:20:11][Step 1/4] Step Update nuGet packages (NuGet Installer) failed
```

The key is the \v10.0\ in the MSBuild path.  I looked at the csproj file mentioned in the error, and it uses the standard compatibility logic to determine the Visual Studio version and set the paths appropriately, only falling back to 10.0 if VisualStudioVersion is null.  I checked in the solution file and I have confirmed that the VisualStudioVersion is 12:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.30110.0
```

Any ideas why NuGet update doesn't seem to be picking up the correct Visual Studio version?

Answer (score 0):

The VisualStudioVersion will be defined when you build from within Visual Studio. On the build server it will not be defined by default.

You should be able to set it through an environment variable on the machine or in Team City. Or just update your project so it fallsback to version 12 instead.

```
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">12.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```

NuGet does not read anything from the solution itself. It just uses it as the base directory from which to find any packages.config files that exist in any subdirectory below the solution.

Comment: I have tried adding a system environment variable VisualStudioVersion=12.0, and it still ends up with the v10.0 path.  I also tried adding env.VisualStudioVersion and apparently it ignores decimal values. :(     I am trying to avoid modifying the projects themselves, but it looks like that might be the solution.